# Match current date with an sql database entry in c++

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-c++

I have **Date** field in my SQL database.
I want only those records to be written inside a file whose date match with current date/ system date.

I can't find any SQL query in ** **for matching the two dates.

What should come in place of ???

`SELECT * FROM attendence where Date = ???`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

depends on date time format

if its **'2012-10-09 15:04:58'**

```
SELECT * FROM attendence where Date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

if its **'2012-10-09'**

```
SELECT * FROM attendence where Date = CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: or instead of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP use NOW()

Comment: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is specific to the time on the client machine, rather than the server.  
Also it depend on session not on server

Comment: lol "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() are synonyms for NOW() " http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp

Answer (score 2):

It worked by doing the following also:

```
SELECT * FROM attendence where Date = '"+System::DateTime::Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") +"'
```

The format in the end is added because the date was added in that format in the database.

Answer (score 0):

unless there is a timezone difference between the mysql database and the endusers (as in a c++ application remotely querying a mysql database in another timezone), this should work fine:

```
SELECT * FROM attendence WHERE Date = CURDATE()
```

if there were a timezone factor to consider, you'd either have to supply the enduser system date as a query parameter, or tell MySQL what timezone the enduser is in and use

```
CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE(), from_tz, to_tz);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
SELECT * FROM attendence where Date(Date) = NOW()
```

Comment: now includes time, it looks like he just had date. If you do time to time matching, it will only return records edited that very same day hour minute & second